# A question about epidemiology calculations: Simpson's paradox

Tags: statistics

I ran into the following statements, which I don't understand. This is from

http://causality.cs.ucla.edu/blog/index.php/2020/07/06/race-covid-mortality-and-simpsons-paradox-by-dana-mackenzie/

Speaking of two graphs, which he shows, he makes the following statement:

> This is a lot to take in, so let me point out what shocked me. The first figure shows that 35.3 percent of diagnosed COVID cases were in “white, non-Hispanic” people. But 49.5 percent of COVID deaths occurred to people in this category. In other words, whites who have been diagnosed as COVID-positive have a 40 percent greater risk of death than non-whites or Hispanics who have been diagnosed as COVID-positive.

How did he get the '*40 percent greater risk*' result?

Answer (score 0):

> How did he get the '40 percent greater risk' result?

I believe they are simply using (0.495 - 0.353) / 0.353 = 0.402